# annotate grouped linear models with dplyr, broom, and ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, broom

I am starting to delve into broom to visualize simple statistical analysis in dplyr/ggplot. I worked out how to get linear models by grouping to work well using by tying in broom::augment.

I have three questions:

1. What is the elegant way to tie in the summary information of the fits (r squared, intercept, p vals) by group back to the original dataframe (in this case all values in the group would be identical)?
2. How could one annotate the regression lines for each group with just a single value to display the r squared and maybe curve fit) in the plot? In particular, how would one get the alignment/color right so that it's clear which text annotation goes with which regression line?
3. After I sorted out how to do the grouped analysis based on some older SO answers, I learned that the `do` is now superseded by `across()`, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to rewrite `do(fit_carb = augment(lm(drat ~ mpg, data = .)))` using `across()`?

```
#// library and data prep
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

data <- mtcars
data$carb <- as.factor(data$carb)

#// generate scatter plot
plot <- 
     ggplot() + 
     geom_point(data = data, aes(x = mpg, y = drat, color = carb)) 

#// use lm function to generate linear regression model
fit <- lm(formula = drat ~ mpg, data = data)

#// tie results back into dataframe
lm_data <- augment(fit)

#// add fitted points and line
plot +    
     ggtitle("scatter plot with fitted points and line") + 
     #// add geom_point and geom_line with lm_data
     geom_point(data = lm_data, aes(x = mpg, y = .fitted), color = "red") +
     geom_line(data = lm_data, aes(x = mpg, y = .fitted), color = "red")


#// linear model by group

lm_data <- data %>%
     #// group by factor
     group_by(carb) %>%
     #// `.` notation means that object gets piped into that place
     do(fit_carb = augment(lm(drat ~ mpg, data = .))) %>% 
     #// unnest table by the augment results
     unnest(fit_carb)

#// add fitted points and line grouped by carb
plot +    
     ggtitle("scatter plot with fitted points and line") + 
     #// add geom_point and geom_line with lm_data
     geom_point(data = lm_data, aes(x = mpg, y = .fitted, group = carb), color = "red") +
     geom_line(data = lm_data, aes(x = mpg, y = .fitted, group = carb, color = carb))
```

[image: ungrouped]

[image: grouped]

Answer (score 3):

You can leave out the `do` dplyr verb and just go for `mutate` or `summarise`. Based on your graphs, would you not prefer `broom::glance`?

```
data %>%
  group_by(carb) %>%
  mutate(glance(lm(mpg ~ drat))) %>%
  dplyr::select(mpg:carb,adj.r.squared,p.value)
## A tibble: 32 x 13
## Groups:   carb [6]
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear carb  adj.r.squared p.value
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>         <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4 4             0.539 0.00943
# 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4 4             0.539 0.00943
# 3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4 1             0.643 0.0185 
# 4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3 1             0.643 0.0185 
# ...
```

As for the plotting, I know this is not what you were really expecting, but if your primary purpose is to graph, in my opinion, the simplest approach is to leverage `ggpubr::stat_regline_equation`:

```
library(ggpubr)
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = mpg, y = drat, color = carb)) + 
  ggtitle("Scatter plot with fitted points and line") + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  stat_regline_equation(label.x = with(data,tapply(mpg,carb,quantile,.6)),
                        label.y = with(data,tapply(drat,carb,max) - 0.2),
                        aes(label = ..adj.rr.label..),
                        show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

You can tweak the regression with additional arguments to `geom_smooth`. If you need the equation, you could do something like `label = paste(..eq.label.., ..adj.rr.label.., sep = "~~~")`

For simple cases, it's often easier to just manually specify `label.x` and `label.y`, but for more complex cases you might use base R `tapply` to dynamically calculate the position. There is a `position =`  argument for `stat_regline_equation`, but I've never gotten it to work.

Comment: Thank you, @Ian. I had stumbled across ggpubr already, but had put it to the side until I get more comfortable with the basics of the tidyverse. But maybe that's not the right approach and I should make use of packages that make stuff simple that otherwise might be harder in the tidyverse alone.

Comment: I will look through the rest of the answer once I am back at my computer.